# Open information on UK properties

Tags: data-request, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, uk, land

I'm looking to find any open data on UK properties.
I have already looked at all the [VOA](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/valuation-office-agency) datasets. And I am aware that the commercial side of the land registry will be becoming free to access towards next year.

I'm more looking for commercial property information, or an easy way to determine commercial properties from residential (other than using VOA business rates, as this is flawed in multiple aspects).

Comment: Not sure: are you looking for real estate price and, if so, specifically for real estate devoted to commercial use?